# Arduino U8glib: how to display text?

Tags: arduino-uno

I have a Nokia 5110 screen using u8gliv. I have it displaying an image and I can get it to display text:

```
   u8g.setFont(u8g_font_osb18);
   u8g.drawStr(0, 20, "PRESS START");
```

The problem is that this font size is way too big. How can I make it smaller? Do I have to use different fonts? If so how do I do that?

Comment: Can somebody explain me how to download a font and upload then to m

Answer (score 2):

Just choose a smaller font. You know, I showed you the documentation earlier. You really should read it, because it contains all the information you need.

For instance, here is the section on the available fonts: https://code.google.com/p/u8glib/wiki/fontgroup - each section contains a link to download the font group which of course you will need to do before you can use it.

You might find something like:

```
u8g.setFont(u8g_font_fixed_v0);
```

more to your liking. And don't forget to download it via the link above first.

Comment: sorry, I did read it but I couldent find much on font size

Comment: It took me 5 seconds - click the `setFont` link, then the `see here for an overview` link, then select a group and see what looks nice. They are real size.